# kivy - how to detect a new swiped page in page layout

Tags: layout, kivy

Is there a way to detect if a new page was swiped with kivy page layout ? Are there any events ?

I need to update a label in another layout according to the swiped page.

Comment: The`PageLayout` has a`page` property that you can bind to.